# Ideal way to include specific files

Tags: php, include

I've been trying to find a way to do this but can't seem to think of a clean, easy way. When a user submits a form (say the registration form), the form validates as follows:

```
   $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $formId = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url : "validation_check.php",
            type : "POST",
            data : $("#" + $formId).serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                $('#' + $formId + ' :input.form_errors').removeClass('form_errors');
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                    document.forms[$formId].submit();
                } else {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        $('#' + $formId + ' :input#' + i).addClass('form_errors');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

`validation_check.php` simply does:

```
echo json_encode(validate($_POST));
```

And lastly, the `validate()` function

```
$errors = array();

// need to only include if on the registration page
include_once 'register.val.php';

if (isset($data['email']) && ($data['email'] == '' || filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'Not a valid email';
}

return $errors;
```

`include_once 'register.val.php';` just contains some if statements like the email one above. My question is, how can I determine which file I would like to include? If I'm registering then I just want to include the `register.val.php`. If I'm saving information I just want to include `edit.val.php`. Any ideas on a neat clean way to do this?

Comment: how about a hidden "task" field where you define if you are in edit or save mode, then you can include using an if/else function :)

Comment: @Xavjer I thought about this but anyone can modify html code through the browser console and change the value.

Comment: of course they can, but always think that you'll need to revalidate anyway. Never validate only using javascript and then passing the arguments as correct. Only use it to check more userfriendly without reloading the page everytime using javascript. Revalidate in your phpcode b4 saving :) javascript can easily be bypassed

Comment: Yeah I know, I do server side validation as well. Thanks for your response.

Comment: So then this should be your solution ;) (For example the CMS Joomla uses the task field nearly the same way :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a $_GET to your script called action with the value of either register or edit:

```
validation_check.php?action=register
```

And then you can do an if (or a switch if you want to add more actions)

```
if($_GET['action'] === 'register')
    include_once('register.val.php');
else
    include_once('edit.val.php');
```

You could also send the action via post, if you are so inclined.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's an option I guess. I [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/8rPXW/) it here and it could work. This might be the only option I have really.

Comment: I do this a lot in my projects for various reasons... One other way that might work, if you are saving these in a database, you could query the database to see if the user already exists.